# Replace empty spaces with zero (0.0) after Import .csv data

Tags: replacement

I imported data from .csv file and it looks like:

```
{"16.363502297525432,43.244734763317744,,"}, \
{"16.363780167440947,43.244734763317744,,"}, <<560687>>, {"16.698891285549443,43.116452884001127,15406.0"}, \
{"16.699169155464958,43.116452884001127,15406.0"}, \
{"16.699447025380469,43.116452884001127,,"}}
```

Data's are {x-coordinate, y-coordinate, point value}. In some of them there is no "point value" and i need to replace them (",,") with "0.0". How to do that?

I import data with

```
OkoBrusjaObjectID = 
 Import["C:\\Users\\Dane\\Desktop\\Samo oko Brusja\\OkoBrusja_ObjectIDpoKoordinatama.csv", "Table"]
```

and first few rows of data source looks like

```
X,Y,ID_rel,
16.363502297525432,43.244734763317744,,
16.363780167440947,43.244734763317744,,
16.364058037356457,43.244734763317744,,
16.364335907271972,43.244734763317744,,
16.364613777187486,43.244734763317744,,
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It looks like the file was not imported correctly, possibly not imported as a CSV at all.  Can you post a sample of the source data and show us the command you use to import it?

Comment: Command is OkoBrusjaObjectID = 
 Import["C:\\Users\\Dane\\Desktop\\Samo oko \
Brusja\\OkoBrusja_ObjectIDpoKoordinatama.csv", "Table"]

Comment: Part of source data looks like (first few rows): X,Y,ID_rel,
16.363502297525432,43.244734763317744,,
16.363780167440947,43.244734763317744,,
16.364058037356457,43.244734763317744,,
16.364335907271972,43.244734763317744,,
16.364613777187486,43.244734763317744,,

Comment: Please edit this information into the question itself, and also format code blocks as such to ensure readability.  Click the edit link below your question.  For help with formatting, click the ? button on the editor toolbar that comes up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way to import CSV files is to use the [`"CSV"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/CSV.html) import format, not `"Table"`.  You'll find this by searching the documentation for "CSV".

Empty entries will be imported as `""`, which you can easily replace using [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ReplaceAll.html):

```
result /. "" -> 0.0
```

Comment: It works perfect, thanks a lot!